# Linking Fonts From a Url to Rails on Heroku Doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When I render this chunk of code in my rails app, it works fine locally, but the fonts won't load when the app is hosted on Heroku.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min.css" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "business-casual.css" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" %>
```

Is there any way to use the urls without actually having to use the assets pipeline?  Those font families are quite large and I don't exactly want to/ know how to make them Heroku/Rails friendly.

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic, but do you really need *ten variants* of each font...?

Comment: Probably not, but I'm not too great with css, so I was avoiding it if I had too.

Comment: According to the docs a `stylesheet_link_tag` bypasses the asset pipeline when the url starts with a proper protocol. Do you get an error? Or what url does is generate in the html code?

Comment: so this is the link to the app I'm working on https://frozen-dusk-9660.herokuapp.com/blog  

What happens is that the link appears normally, but my main stylesheet doesn't pick up that there are fonts available for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you are accessing your blog though https protocol but the css used for the font is hosted on http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic which is using http protocol so those assets are not loaded because on a non secure network.

You should use this instead https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic"

Comment: You have just fixed it.  Now it works,  Thank you.  I'd upvote but it won't let me do so just yet.